# Kubernetes-dashboard - error trying to reach service: dial tcp 10.36.0.1:8443: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-dashboard

I googled and searched for the answer to my dilemma all answers I could find are not applicable, but they say this has been discussed many times.

Below is my actual cluster setup. 4 worker nodes, two masters, and one load balancer.

[image: Kubernetes Cluster Setup]

I installed the dashboard

```
XXXX@master01:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                busybox                                      1/1     Running   30         30h
kube-system            coredns-78cb77577b-lbp87                     1/1     Running   0          30h
kube-system            coredns-78cb77577b-n7rvg                     1/1     Running   0          30h
kube-system            weave-net-d9jb6                              2/2     Running   7          31h
kube-system            weave-net-nsqss                              2/2     Running   0          39h
kube-system            weave-net-wnbq7                              2/2     Running   7          31h
kube-system            weave-net-zfsmn                              2/2     Running   0          39h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b59f7d4df-dhcpn   1/1     Running   0          28h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-665f4c5ff-6qnzp         1/1     Running   7          28h
```

I installed my service accounts and assigned them cluster-admin roles

```
XXXX@master01:~$ kubectl get sa -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   SECRETS   AGE
default                1         28h
kube-apiserver         1         25h
kubernetes-dashboard   1         28h
```

I am using the kube-apiserver user service account because it was easy to just load the certs in the browser I already have them.

Now I try to access the dashboard using the load balancer:
*https://loadbalancer.local:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/*

at this point one would think I should get the dashboard and every question I have encountered makes that assumption but I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "error trying to reach service: dial tcp 10.36.0.1:8443: i/o timeout",
  "code": 500
}
```

so I decided to pull the logs:

```
kubectl logs -n kubernetes-dashboard service/kubernetes-dashboard                                                                   

Error from server: Get "https://worker04:10250/containerLogs/kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-665f4c5ff-6qnzp/kubernetes-dashboard": x509: certificate signed by unknown
authority
```

all I get is this one line and I had an idea of finding out what the issue is with the certification from this worker node: **worker04:10250**
I used OpenSSL to check the certificate and I discovered the following:
worker04 has generated its own certificate alright, but it also generated its own CA as well.

and this is where I am with no idea how to fix this and bring up a dashboard.
I also tried a proxy on **master01**:

```
kubectl -v=9 proxy --port=8001 --address=192.168.1.24
```

and all I got was 403 Forbidden!

Comment: What command exactly are you using to access the dashboard? And from where are you executing it?

Comment: I am using this endpoint: https://loadbalancer:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services (which is working) but the dashboard itself (https://loadbalancer:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/) this is the one that doesn't work

Comment: You access this URL with your web browser? From your local machine?

Comment: i am access the URL from my web browser on my local machine(windows), the loadbalancer is my remote (linux machine)

Answer (score 2):

I made some progress with this, I figured out that when a node generate and registers itself to a cluster, it is generating its own certificate CSR signed by its own generated CA, to fix this I generated the certificates for all the nodes signed by the cluster CA and simply replaced the auto generated certificates and restarted the nodes..